# idempiere workflow document process

Tags: idempiere

I am using idempiere 2.1. I am new to idempiere so now I am doing tutorial from wiki page. This is tutorial I am doing:http://wiki.idempiere.org/en/Developing_Plug-Ins_-_Models,_Documents_and_custom_accounting. 
When I finish all steps, I start to test workflow, but in first window when I fill in information, then click Document Action and it displays error 'Document Status changed - Requery Record'. After that, nothing happened, workflow not working. Can someone help me on this problem?
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tfACB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Understand that a window tab on display is in an open or editable state. A **process** button though can update any data in the present window as well as any table across the database, it should not do things like **save** the present window as that is done by the Save button. Without looking at your code, i assumed that is probably what happened in it. If you do not have something like <*presentTabTable*>.save() then post the Data type or objects with the save() snips and perhaps it will be obvious to point out.

p/s - I noticed your screenshot is about battle plan by ROK. Not planning to invade the North are you? :) Just joking!